# Loss function and Last layer for numeric output

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, loss-function

I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network to read the consumption index from a valid picture of a meter. The consumption is an **integer** that can vary from 0 to 99999.
What loss function should I use, what is the appropriate shape for the last layer on the neural network ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a regression problem, so usually the output layer for this kind of networks is a simple Dense layer with output shape 1 and linear activation function. As loss function you can use MSE or logcosh